# Does R have a method or package for getting system hardware specifications?

Tags: r, hardware

I am trying to benchmark some R code, which will be run on several machines with very different levels of perforamnce to more fully understand its behavior. I am writing log files, but I would like to include in those log files the system specifications of the machine running the code. `Sys.info()` does not provide the information I'm looking for which would be things like available RAM, processor type, etc. Is there an alternate command or package I should look at to get this information?

Comment: I guess it will be OS specific and it may not work on all Operating Systems. I would also love to know if such function exists.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any built-in function at this point. What I'm doing right now is just using `system2` and just writing out to my log text file. It's not elegant but it should work.

Comment: I found this package called "benchmarkme" https://github.com/csgillespie/benchmarkme#machine-specs which you may find useful.

Comment: Thank you! The `benchmarkme` package seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: You may also be able to get this information by running system commands. Something like this should work on Windows `df <- read.csv(text = system("systeminfo /FO csv", intern = TRUE))`

Comment: thanks to @MattJewett you command is what i need, and is there a command that works in mac system